# Inserting Space/Separator after Select-String -Context

Tags: powershell

I have a script that reads  series of log files located in different places and looks for an error code with Select-String.  After the error code I print out the next four lines to a file with "-Context".  That file's content gets dumped into an email and sent off.

```
$logsToCheck = "F:\Log1.log",
               "F:\log2.log",
               "F:\log3.log"
$logsToCheck | % {Select-String -Path $_  -Pattern "SQLCODE:2627" -Context 
0, 4} | Out-File $dupChkFile
$emailbody = Get-Content $dupChkFile | ConvertTo-Html
```

The actual output of the string is poorly formatted and runs together.  Is there a way to add blank lines or spaces after the last line when using Select-String -Context?

Originally I was piping the $emailbody to a Out-String but changed it to HTML to try to clear up formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try reading out the match and context separately.

```
Select-String -Path $_ "SQLCODE:2627" -Context 0,2 | %{ 
    $_.Line
    $_.Context.PostContext
    "-----Separator-----"
}
```

the default output of `Select-String` with `Context` is human-readable modified, this will return everything as an array of unmodified strings, so you can be sure there will always be newlines, and it will behave better with other cmdlt's including `Out-String` or loops.

Comment: This definately cleans up the output but still makes the output run together from the multiple logs.  Is there a way I could add some kind of space or separator after the last line?  I thought about trying something with the LineNumber property, adding two lines maybe?

Comment: @J235711 Insert for example `"----- {0}:{1} -----" -f $_.FileName,$_.LineNumber`  as the 2nd line

Comment: @J235711 updated there to make sure there's a clear line.

Comment: This solved my problem.  Just simply added the line like that worked great @LotPings

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using concatenation:

```
% { "$(Select-String -Path $_ -Pattern 'SQLCODE:2627' -Context 0, 4)`r`n" } |
  Out-File $dupChkFile -Append
```